# Angular multiple .subscribe in for

Tags: angular, asynchronous, subscribe

Hy, how can I "doSometihg" with the correct final value of total?

```
let total: number = 0;
for (let articleId in items) {
  this.articleService.getArticleById(articleId).subscribe((article: Articles[]) => {//Async  
    total = totale + article.price;
  })
}
doSometihg(total);
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

Use fork join to run all async calls in parallel and wait for them to complete.

When the articles come back, you can get the total and continue processing.

```js
forkJoin(
  items.map(articleId => this.articleService.getArticleById(articleId))
).subscribe((articles: Article[]) => {
  const total: number = articles
    .reduce((cumulative, article) => cumulative + article.price, 0);
  doSomething(total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
const allObs = forkJoin(...children.map(r => r.validate()));
allObs.subscribe(res => console.log(res)); // Do what you want with the array of results
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.